# FactoryGirl - Faker image for CarrierWave uploader

Tags: carrierwave, factory-bot, faker

How can I use Faker's avatar generation with a FactoryGirl Factory ?

`Faker::Avatar.image` returns a URL with an image, can I somehow try to download it during a FactoryGirl create action, so I can use it as a Carrierwave image (and fallback to no image of the download fails) ?

Answer (score 1):

I have a factory which is uploading faker images to Cloudinary using Carrierwave. It's not exactly what you described, but maybe helps?

Anyway, the attribute in my database is called `image_location` but I have to edit this in the factory (and in my seeds) to `remote_[ATTRIBUTE NAME]_url`

So, my factory has
`remote_image_location_url Faker::Avatar.image`

Comment: Thank you very much!